# How can I put an "info" button on the iPhone nav bar?

Tags: iphone

I want to put an 'i' button on the nav bar (on all the screens in which the nav bar appears). Touching on that button should bring up a view (perhaps modal) in which I can have controls. How do I put the button on the nav bar, and what how will I execute the call back?

Answer (score 64):

Info Button Code:

```
UIButton* infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
    [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(infoButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *modalButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:modalButton animated:YES];
    [modalButton release];
```

The code above calls  method -(void)infoButtonAction. Add this to all of your ViewControllers or just create one .nib and use that for all of your views.

Comment: Perfect. I have two view controllers. Root and Detail. I added this code to both. I changed Left to Right. I also added:

- (void) infoButtonAction {
 NSLog(@"Information");
}

It works fine. Each of my view controllers already have their own xib files as well. 

When you said "use that nib for all your views" what did you mean? I would love to have a simple view with static information show up. Sorry for the newb question. What is the simplest way to do that?

Comment: How do I format the comment so that the code block shows up correctly as a code block.

Comment: I was thinking that since you need this viewController for every view, you can create a viewController with the code above in the -viewDidLoad or -awakeFromNib method. Then subclass this viewController for each viewController you need. That way you only have the one place where the code for infoButton is. Just an idea.

Comment: This reusable code could be placed in a UIBarButtonItem category.

Answer (score 10):

You can also achieve it on storyboard.Drag a UIButton to you navigation bar instead of the usual UIBarButtonItem. You will see that your unbutton will be "nested" inside the bar button item which can be expanded.

[image]

Then you can change your button's type property  to info light | dark from the attribute inspector.

[image]